# How are controller actions and views rendered through a single entry script in php frameworks?

Tags: php, symfony, yii

For example in a [Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com) application the url is in this format

`www.example.com/index.php?r=foo/bar`

Which renders the script inside the `actionBar()` method of class `FooController`. Further, this class (or its parent class) implements a `render()` method which can render a view file. 
All the url's are handled through the entry script `index.php`.

I would like to write my own class which can handle url's through this way.
Can someone give me a **very basic** *'hello world'* example of writing such a script ?

Comment: You need a simple controller/action or you want redefine the url manager?

Comment: I want my own simple controller/action @Elwinar's answer is definitely in the right direction.. you have answered many questions about Yii2, I would be thankful if you write an answer to this.

Comment: I'm sorry these issues related to the answer provided by Elwinar are not of interest to me ..I use a framework like yii in order not to deal with these issues .. I prefer to deal with controller / action .. ie issues related to applications .. anyway thank you for the courtesy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give it a shot:

```
// index.php
$r = $_REQUEST['r']; // 'foo/bar'
$rParts = explode('/',$r);
$foo = $rParts[0];
$bar = $rParts[1];
$controller = new $foo; // foo
echo $controller->$bar();
```

Comment: good shot! can we say that 'basically' this is how these frameworks work?

Comment: but this does not include how a view file is rendered by calling `$bar()`. I know that requires a separate implementation but I hope you can give a very basic example of that as well :)

Comment: I'll leave the view as an exercise for the student.  Frankly, the notion of explicitly specifying the controller/action in a url strikes me as a bit bizarre.

Comment: but that can be handled through mod_rewrite. my basic problem was the above.  I really appreciate you have made this complex thing sooo simple! thanks again:)

Comment: one may consider a vote for my question if you think it'll help people in the future ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did for a friend recently, when teaching him how frameworks works. This is a basic example, but it demonstrates how a container works, how to handle the router, giving the controller a request and a response and handling redirects and the like.

```
<?php
require 'autoload.php';

$container = [];

$container['controller.elephant'] = function() {
    return new Controller\Elephant();
};

$routes = [];

$routes['/babar'] = 'controller.elephant:babar';
$routes['/celeste'] = 'controller.elephant:celeste';

$request = new Request();

if (!isset($routes[$request->path()])) {
    http_response_code(404);
    exit;
}

$route = $routes[$request->path()];
list($class, $method) = explode(':', $route);

$controller = $container[$class]();
$response = $controller->{$method}($request, new Response());

if ($response->isRedirect()) {
    http_response_code($response->status());
    header('Location: '.$response->destination());
} else {
    echo $response->content();
}

exit;
```

I won't include anything more than that (albeit there is other files) because it would bloat the answer needlessly (I can send them to you by other means if you want to).

I highly advise you to look at the [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) code, as it is a micro framework that basically do just that.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but I still find it pretty complex, as I don't know what is inside the Request, Response and Controller classes. Is it possible to make it simpler? I first need to understand the basic idea behind, how this "single entry script system" works?

Answer (score 0):

Well in the Symfony documentation you have this page: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html

where it explains how is the life cycle of a request, it's just a flow diagram.

But it will give you a really good idea on how you should build yours

If you are more interested in how based on a url you get the controller you should read the RoutingComponent in symfony

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html

But if you want to write your own class, you should use something like regex expression groups where you can detect the url parts separated by i.e: '/' then you somehow map the url to the controller i.e associative array 'Hash'

someurl.com/someController/someAction

```
 $mappings = [
   ...
   'someController' => 'The\Controller\Class'
 ]

 $controller = new $mappings[$urlControllerPart]();

 $response = $controller->{$urlActionPart}($request);

 return $response;
```